# Summernote returning empty string

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, summernote

I'm trying to using summernote with JSF but i don't know why this always return empty string:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Conteúdo *</label>
                                <h:inputTextarea value="#{cursoMB.paginaConteudo.conteudo}"
                                    id="conteudo" required="true"
                                    requiredMessage="O conteúdo é obrigatório"
                                    styleClass="form-control summernote">
                                </h:inputTextarea>
                            </div>
```

In my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initSummerNote();
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(initSummerNoteAjax);
});

function initSummerNoteAjax(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') {
        jQuery('.summernote').summernote({
            height : 300, // set editor height

            minHeight : null, // set minimum height of editor
            maxHeight : null, // set maximum height of editor

            focus : false
        // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        });
    }
}
```

When the modal is called the summernote is showed but when i save the content of textarea is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the summernote plugin not store the edited text in the textarea to get the edited text you have to call  `jQuery('.summernote').code()`

I suggest you that in the button that you call to store the value add a javascript handler to get the text and add to textarea with that jsf store the string in the 
paginaConteudo.conteudo property

```
function beforeSubmit() {
    jQuery('.summernote').text(jQuery('.summernote').code());
}
```

Also I suggest you to destroy the widget before recreating the ajax call

```
jQuery('.summernote').destroy().summernote({..........
```

---

Note for people using **summernote after v0.7.0**: You must use `.summernote('code')` and `.summernote('destroy')` now.

> After v0.7.0, direct jquery methods, destroy and code were removed for avoiding conflict with other jquery libraries. You can call this methods with summernote api.

See also http://summernote.org/getting-started/#get-amp-set-code

Comment: I'm trying to add in onsubmit of jSF Form but javascript function is not called. See: <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false" onsubmit="setSummernoteText()">

Comment: I meant that you have a button that saves the value of the summernote maybe a <h:commandButton /> add the onclick="beforeSubmit"

Comment: worked now but when i insert a image the tomcat crashs. Do you have any ideia ?

Comment: You have to check the stacktrace in tomcat the main problem is that the summernote returns the image as an html tag and the src value of the image could cause some problem in the moment jsf try to update the model with that html string.

Comment: THanks that problem was my database, i change varchar(255) to text and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

For your all used summernote textarea, you must make a loop and set real values to real textarea.

```
    function beforeSubmit()
    {
     $('.summernote').each(function(v){
         $(this).val($(this).code());
      });
    }
```

Comment: This summernote is textarea so you must change this   $(this).val($(this).code()); must chage  $(this).html($(this).code());